# pidgin after source compilation not working

Tags: 12.04, pidgin

I have downloaded the **pidgin** source code from the following location.

http://www.pidgin.im/download/source/

After compilation, when i run the pidgin, i don't see any option for IM sites (like Facebook, gtalk.. etc). I have attached a screen shot to show the issue.

Please help[image: screen shot of Pidgin launch]

As it is showing in screen, there is no option coming in **protocol** drop down list.

Comment: Start pidgin with -d for debug info: ./pidgin -d. Did you disable plugins during compilation? See this link for some info: https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Installing%20Pidgin#Isthereawaytocompilewithoutsomeprotocols

Comment: What about the errors shown in the terminal? Do they have anything to do with your problem?

Comment: checking for FARSTREAM... no

checking for FARSTREAM... no
configure: error: 
Dependencies for voice/video were not met.
Install the necessary gstreamer and farstream packages first.
Or use --disable-vv if you do not need voice/video support.
   
vivek@viveks:~/pidgin/pidgin-2.10.7$ ./configure --disable-vv

Comment: which package of FARSTREAM is pidgin looking for? any idea??

Answer (score 3):

```
checking for GSTINTERFACES... yes
checking for FARSTREAM... no
checking for FARSTREAM... no
configure: error: 
Dependencies for voice/video were not met.
Install the necessary gstreamer and farstream packages first.
Or use --disable-vv if you do not need voice/video support.
```

For these particular errors, installing `libfarstream-0.1-dev` and `libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev` solved the issue for me (on Ubuntu 12.04 64b).